# Karate - How to extract from Json Response and use as data driven data in Outline Scenario

Tags: karate

Using the below response, I want to extract the ID fields where created_by.$oid is equal to '5bf6d22a60664323c10676cf' and use the extracted Ids as data driven data for Outline Scenarios. Which is the most effective way to do so?

[
{
"deleted": false,
"processing": false,
"id": "5ffff5b36bdfca2cb8f11135",
"created_by": {
"$oid": "3bf6d24a60664343c10676cf"
}
},
{
"deleted": false,
"processing": false,
"id": "600070616bdfca4f2045824f",
"created_by": {
"$oid": "5bf6d22a60664323c10676cf"
}
},
{
"deleted": false,
"processing": false,
"id": "6001907f38d61400080376f4",
"created_by": {
"$oid": "5bf6d22a60664323c10676cf"
}
}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, and please refer to the docs for how this works: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

```
* def fun = function(x){ return x.created_by['$oid'] == '5bf6d22a60664323c10676cf' }
* def filtered = karate.filter(response, fun)
* def ids = $filtered[*].id
* print ids
```